# Как реализовать отправку SMS или email оповещений при выполнении конкретного процесса в базе данных mysql?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Использую базу данных mysql. Имеется две таблицы с идентичными столбцами, во вторую дублируются данные удовлетворяющие условию прописанному в триггере. Как правильно и какими средствами можно реализовать отправку оповещений, содержащих информацию из строк второй таблицы по электронной почте или смс? Более простым языком: в таблицу 2 добавилась запись, нужно отправить письмо или сообщение, что в таблицу 2 записана новая запись и данные из добавленной строки (дата, время, номер телефона, страна, оператор).
Приветствуются ссылки, примеры кода.
Использую Ubuntu 16.04, phpmyadmin, mysql.
Заранее премного благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Это должен быть некий внешний процесс, написанный на любом известном вам и желательно подходящем языке, который будет постоянно опрашивать БД на предмет появления новых строк и выполнять рассылки

Comment: @Mike почти правильно)

Answer (score 1):

Делай новый триггер, который дернет sys_exec

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `test_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `trig_test` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @exec_var = sys_exec(CONCAT('/usr/local/bin/send_sms +792312345678 "', NEW.id, NEW.date, '"'));
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Для проектов с упором на надежность скрипт отправки должен поставить сообщения в очередь на отправку, а другой скрипт их оттуда выгребает.

Очередь реализуется через fifo, socket или через папку с файлами через inotify. Для чего-то крупного через брокер kafka/rabbit.

Comment: А если в этот момент связи с смс центром не будет и программа аварийно завершится, нужен же планировщик рассылок который контролирует, что доставка прошла. Идея с вызовом внешней программы конечно интересна, но я бы на триггера, срабатывающие один раз не рассчитывал. А еще при проблемах в сети программа может пару минут повисеть на таймауте ...

Comment: в smstools есть планировщик отправки, сообщения копятся в исходящих. если sendmail-ить через локальный exim, то также ссобщения копятся в исходящих. если пулять на апи провайдера смс - то да, возможны потери, но в случае с опросом таблицы можно потеряить в деньгах если чтото упадет)